# IE not accept variables in a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get IE to center my popup window and the following code will open the window:

```
function open_win()
{
    window.open("http://google.com","_blank","toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no,     status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=640, height=560");
}
```

but then if I these variables:

```
function open_win(pageURL, title,w,h)
{
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
    window.open("http:google.com","_blank","toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=640, height=560");

}
```

then IE won't open the new window.  It stops working when I add variables anywhere. WTF is up with IE it's really pissing me off all other Browsers accept the variables just fine.

Comment: Could you include the code that is calling your open_win function?

Comment: Check the console to see if any errors are appearing.

Comment: Where did you used left and top variables

Comment: Fixing the typo in the url, the code runs fine: http://jsfiddle.net/EzWmD/show/ Please show us the actual code if it is different so we might be able to help out.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass an invalid value to that function, an error will be thrown inside it. For example, say I pass either a string or `undefined` as the `w` parameter. The variables you expect to be numbers in your function will become `NaN`.

An error might happen right there, and if so the `window.open` call might not be not made. So sanitize your input, and check your logic that calls that function to see what's happening.

Also, the console is your friend. You changed the signature of the function, and we haven't seen the code that calls it in your question. If you are manipulating the arguments, it might be that the function isn't even being called anymore due to an error. So please include any errors you see in the console as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should include:

```
"top=" + top + ", left=" + left
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDTFa/)

```
function open_win(pageURL, title,w,h)
{
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
    window.open("http://www.google.com","_blank","toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=640, height=560, top=" + top + ", left=" + left);

}
```

Comment: I rewrote the code to this:

<script>
function open_win()

{
var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
</script>

Then I call the function like this:

  <a onclick="PopupCenter('http:google.com', 'My Popup',700,560);" href="javascript:void(0);">Center My Popup</a>

but it is still failing.

Comment: You removed function parameters!! Use function open_win(pageURL, title, w, h)